# ffmpeg - coordinate system

Tags: ffmpeg

This is a pretty simple question yet i couldn't find the answer to it anywhere. 
How does ffmpeg's coordinate system work? Meaning - for all operations such as `crop` and `overlay`, is the (0,0) point at the bottom left or top left?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Top left.

Pixels in a raw video stream are stored left to right, top to bottom. And all filters work on uncompressed frames, so that's the easiest way to setup the co-ordinate system as well.